# scrapy Request not yielding any output

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to adapt the "Following links" example in http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html to my own spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from funda.items import FundaItem

class PropertyLinksSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "property_links"
    allowed_domains = ["funda.nl"]

    def __init__(self, place='amsterdam', page='1'):
        self.start_urls = ["http://www.funda.nl/koop/%s/p%s/" % (place, page)]
        self.base_url = "http://www.funda.nl/koop/%s/" % place
        self.le1 = LinkExtractor(allow=r'%s+huis|appartement-\d{8}' % self.base_url)

    def parse(self, response):
        links = self.le1.extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            if link.url.count('/') == 6 and link.url.endswith('/'):
                item = FundaItem()
                item['url'] = link.url
                yield scrapy.Request(link.url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//title').extract()
        yield item
```

However, if I try to run this using the command

```
scrapy crawl property_links -a place=amsterdam -a page=1 -o property_links_test.json
```

I get an empty .json file:

```
[
```

In a previous version of this spider, I had the `parse` method simply `yield item` the spider was producing a .json file with links as expected. I've also checked, using the Scrapy shell, that the pages have titles. So I don't understand why I'm not getting any output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were not parsing the items to second function this code works fine for me.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class FundaItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()

class PropertyLinksSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "property_links"
    allowed_domains = ["funda.nl"]

    def __init__(self, place='amsterdam', page='1'):
        self.start_urls = ["http://www.funda.nl/koop/%s/p%s/" % (place, page)]
        self.base_url = "http://www.funda.nl/koop/%s/" % place
        self.le1 = LinkExtractor(allow=r'%s+huis|appartement-\d{8}' % self.base_url)

    def parse(self, response):
        links = self.le1.extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            if link.url.count('/') == 6 and link.url.endswith('/'):
                item = FundaItem()
                item['url'] = link.url
                yield scrapy.Request(link.url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents, meta={'item': item})

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        new_item = response.request.meta['item']
        new_item['title'] = response.xpath('//title').extract()
        yield new_item
```